# Telnet Ip address Ip

Tags: asp.net, protocols

I am calling someone's API in my webform. The used method for this is posted.I am getting a response from there end as the HTTP status code is 'Ok'.Still, they want telnet results.

So In the command prompt, I have done like this

telnet Ipadress port and click .

I got a response as 'Not recognized as internal and External command'

So from the windows feature, I turned on 'Telnet client'

And checked. I got a black screen. That means the test connection is ok.

Can Make telnet client on is dangers?

I immediately off telnet client from windows feature.

Will they receive my machine access? Even if I off telnet client?

Comment: _"Still, they want telnet results"_ - what?

Answer (score 0):

> Will they receive my machine access? Even if I off telnet client?

On TCP & IP level, yes, since the connection is successfully make, the server side may have access log from your IP address.

On application / HTTP level, I doubt, since the handshake of HTTP protocol is not completed.